# Conditional cell counting based on row or column header values

Tags: excel

Consider the following:

[image]

C9 computes the number of YES cells whose row header or column header is Team1. C10 computes the number of YES cells whose whose row header or column header is Team2.

What should the formula for C9 and C10 be?

Comment: are the `NA` typed in or are they the actual `#N/A` error?

Comment: NA are typed-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula should be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$3:$A$6=B9)+($C$1:$F$1=B9)>0)*($C$3:$F$6="YES"))
```

Basically the formula is saying:

IF ($A$3:$A$6=B9 OR $C$1:$F$1=B9) AND $C$3:$F$6="YES" then count it.

Each Boolean will resolve to the bit value True = 1 and False = 0. So if either or both of the first are True it will be greater than 0 and that will resolve to 1.  Then we multiply it to the third.  So if either of the two resolve to False or 0 it will add 0, if both resolve to True then it will add 1.

The SUMPRODUCT adds them all together and we get the count.

[image]