# explanation for complicated sumproduct formula

Tags: excel

This question is in relation to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520380/conditional-cell-counting-based-on-row-or-column-header-values).

Would anyone be kind enough to please help me understand this formula?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$3:$A$6=B9)+($C$1:$F$1=B9)>0)*($C$3:$F$6="YES"))
```

Comment: This is a **question and answer** site. Note that **question** is **singular**, not plural. The general rule is that you ask one question per post, which in some cases can be extended to two if they're closely related. It *never* extends to a numbered list of a half dozen, especially when you're asking for a tutorial.

Comment: Google.com is great. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function

Comment: All you had to do was ask for an explanation.  I have provided one in the original answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT((($A$3:$A$6=B9)+($C$1:$F$1=B9)>0)*($C$3:$F$6="YES"))

First thing to accept is that this function uses arrays, not single values, hence the ranges in the arguments.

`$A$3:$A$6=B9`creates a one dimensional array of `True`/`False` depending if each cell in the range is equal to B9.

`$C$1:$F$1=B9`does the same thing, although this reference is horizontal

So the formula now contains two one dimensional arrays of equal length that are populated with `True` / `False` values (also represented as zero's and one's).

The act of adding them together means we now have one array with the value 0, in the case that neither value was equal to B9 for the two cells considered, 1 in the case one value was equal or 2 if both were equal.

This is then run through a logical `>0` which says if a value in the one dimensional array of zero's, one's and two's is larger than zero, it is true. This basically keeps all the zeros and converts them to false and changes any other value to true.

The other part `$C$3:$F$6="YES"` creates an array of equal length with `true` if a range value is equal to 'YES' and `false` if not.

Bearing in mind that each array of `true` / `false` can be expressed as 0/1 and the two values multiplied together, this results in a single array of 1's and 0's that can be summed to give a total that corresponds to:

The number of values where A3:A6 is equal to B9 or C1:F1 is equal to B9 and C3:F6 is equal to 'YES'

The following array formula does the same thing (press ctrl+shift+enter, not just enter when entering it into the cell to get it to work), then use 'Evaluate Formula' found under the FORMULAS menu to see it in action step by step:

`=SUM(--((--(A3:A6=A9)+--(C1:F1=A9))>0)*--(C3:F6="YES"))`

Comment: hi james, thanks for your response, do you mean that `(($A$3:$A$6=B9)+($C$1:$F$1=B9)>0)` results to a 1D array? if so, how can it be multiplied to the 2D array of `($C$3:$F$6="YES")`? or is `($C$3:$F$6="YES")` implicitly converted to a 1D array?

Comment: No problems - have a look at this http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/05/26/advanced-sumproduct-queries/, I imagine the formula implicitly converts the 2D array to 1D and then 'stacks' the 1D array next to it to produce two 1D arrays of equal length that can be multiplied and summed to give the correct answer. This is also how the stats language R treats these cases when presented with two 1D arrays of unequal length that have to be combined

Comment: Can check this later (currently on my mobile)

Answer (score 1):

1-What does `$A$3:$A$6=B9` mean?
It evaluates to True when any cell `A3:A6=B9` ="Team1" in your example
$A$3:$A$6 $ to fix the references in case you drag the formula

2-What does `$C$1:$F$1=B9` mean?
Same as above it evaluates to True when any cell `C1:F1=B9` ="Team1" in your example
$C$1:$F$1 $ to fix the references when you drag the formula

3-What does `(($A$3:$A$6=B9)+($C$1:$F$1=B9)>0)` mean?
Each True in the above 1 & 2 will become 1 when True (using +)
If both True 1+1>0 if one is True 1+0>0 or 0+1>0

4-What does `$C$3:$F$6="YES"` mean?
If you have Yes in any cells between C3:F6 it will evaluate to True(1)

5-What does multiplying `(($A$3:$A$6=B9)+($C$1:$F$1=B9)>0)` with `$C$3:$F$6="YES"` mean?
True =1, False=0
When you multiply only values 1*1 will count

6-What does taking the:
 `SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$6=B9)+($C$1:$F$1=B9)>0)*($C$3:$F$6="YES")` mean?
Sumproduct will sum the 1 resulting from the product, it means count when the product is 1